# C#.net decorator pattern converting/setting collection

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Have a question about how to better optimize or speed things up. Currently my code seems to be running a bit slow...

I have the following classes

```
public class DataFoo : IFoo { }

public class Foo
{
     internal IFoo UnderlyingDataObject{get;set;}

     public Foo(IFoo f)
     {
          UnderlyingDataObject = f;
     }
}
```

Now, in many cases I end up needing or calling a method that will provide back a List. This method will initially get a array of DataFoo objects and will iterate over all returned objects instantiating a new Foo object passing in the DataFoo... Here's an example...

```
public List<Foo> GetListOfFoo(Guid id)
{
     DataFoo[] q = GetArrayOfDataFoo(id);
     List<Foo> rv = new List<Foo>();

     for(var i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
     {
           rv.Add(new Foo(q[i]));
     }
     return rv;
}
```

The issue is that having to iterate over and instantiate like this seems pretty slow. I was curious if anyone might have suggestions on how to speed this up...

Comment: Have you profiles your code to verify that a) it is running slow and b) this code is the bottleneck?

Comment: i'm converting the code from a existing linq to sql implementation to this approach using nhibernate/fluent nhibernate...

from what i'm seeing comparing the two versions; the new code is slower. which it's slower either because nhibernate was introduced or because of all the for loops that are occurring...

Comment: Use a profiler to check for performance bottlenecks - not guesswork; they are rarely where you expect. I would expect the change of ORM provider to be much more significant than looping performance.

Comment: How many items are you talking about?  What kind of response times are you expecting?  Are we talking microseconds or seconds?

Comment: See that's the thing. We're not talking about huge amounts of items. Max maybe 500...

Anyone want to recommend a good profiling tool..?

Comment: I personally use DotTrace from JetBrains for profiling.  It does a good job of both performance and memory profiling, but it's a little pricey.  You can evaluate it for 10 days from memory though.

Comment: You might also use an NHibernate profiler.  I believe Ayende Rahien has one.

Comment: There's also a free one at http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should profile this carefully.  Whenever you're looking at performance, don't try and guess what's going on -- measure everything.  You will, more often than not, be surprised by the truth.

Your definition of `GetListOfFoo` could be improved slightly to avoid needless resizing of the `List<Foo>` by specifying the initial capacity:

```
 DataFoo[] q = GetArrayOfDataFoo(id);
 List<Foo> rv = new List<Foo>(q.Length);
```

But unless you're dealing with very large arrays and are concerning yourself with very small periods of time, then this won't make much difference.

There's nothing about the decorator pattern you're using that should effect your performance noticably unless you're talking about millions of updates a second or microsecond latencies.

I would like to see what `GetArrayOfDataFoo` is doing.  My guess is that your issue is occurring outside what you have shown us.

Comment: Cheers; I missed the conversion ;-p

Comment: GetArrayOfDataFoo is using fluent nhibernate/nhibernate and linq to nhibernate to simply make a linq call to the database and get back an array of objects...

Comment: Then I would focus your energy on that area of your code, rather than the decorator pattern or conversion.  That's just the tip of the iceberg.  Use a profiler to find out what's going on.  I believe Ayende Rahien has an NHibernate profiler, but I haven't used it myself.